# Payment options not showing after enabling them in woocommerce payment.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, configuration, payment-gateway

I am using WordPress and woocommerce plugin. In this case there is some default payment method. I have installed other payment methods. However after proper configuration. The payment method is not showing in the webpage.

I am looking for someone who can help me on this.

Thanking you
Sandipta Roy

Comment: Why are you so sure that the configuration is correct?

Comment: I have followed all the recommended process. You are correct, may be can you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

After installing and activating the payment plugin, you need to go to woocommerce settings, select payment option and from there you need to activate the payment method.

Comment: I did the same there as well even then not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this workflow:
    - uninstall the other payment methods
    - check if the one desired payment method is activated
    - check if the payment method is configured correctly
    - check if the payment method is now showing on your webpage

Answer (score 0):

Another possible Reason for the Payment Gateway to not be shown is that the Price of the Products in the cart is no more than 0 €. In that case the Heading payment Methods will be shown but not more then that